# Understanding and fixing partition scheme (Fedora28)

Tags: linux, partition-table

I recently wanted to dual-boot my laptop (Lenovo Yoga 710) running Windows 10 to include Fedora 28. I previously played around with the laptop and ended up messing up my partition scheme. I would like to understand my system and how to optimise my hard drive to have no unnecessary partitions.

```
[keith@localhost ~]$ sudo sfdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2B5259A5-F9D8-40DE-BD9B-642290CE530A

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    534527    532480  260M EFI System
/dev/sda3     567296   2664447   2097152    1G Linux filesystem 
/dev/sda4  420067328 422164479   2097152    1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  474544128 498069503  23525376 11.2G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda8  422164480 472496127  50331648   24G Linux LVM
/dev/sda9    2664448 420067327 417402880  199G Linux LVM

Partition table entries are not in disk order.


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora00-root: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-swap: 2.5 GiB, 2688548864 bytes, 5251072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora00-swap: 7.7 GiB, 8204058624 bytes, 16023552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 21.5 GiB, 23077060608 bytes, 45072384 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora00-home: 141.4 GiB, 151817027584 bytes, 296517632 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange site! Please review the [help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) for information on how to best post on this site. First off, could you please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/473214/edit) your post to change your pictures of text to just be text. It makes it much more readable, people can copy and paste from it and text is search engine addressable so others can better find this question. Second, I would instead include the output of `lsblk` to give a better idea of each partition. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First off, it's hard determining what the partitions are used for without seeing where they're mounted. You can do that by using either `mount` or `lsblk` - I prefer the latter option as it gives more clean output.

The first partition - the EFI partition - is where you have your efi-stubs. Those are required by windows and (whatever bootloader you've chosen for fedora idk) to boot.
The two 1G partitions seems quite unnecessary to me but idk what they're used for.

In reality you may only need 3 partitions, 1 UEFI, 1 Linux and 1 Windows (also plus that 1 windows recovery part. but that's up to you) but that's not ideal.

You may have your home folder on a separate (Linux, EXT4) partition and an optional shared partition that you can use to share files between your windows and fedora system.

Comment: Thanks for the info, 'lsblk -l' was a great help, it showed the mountpoints for my partitions.